# member variable is not updating when database event gets triggered

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have a gameobject in a scene with a script attached that retrieves data from firebase realtime database. It's something like this -

```
public class A: Monobehaviour{
    private bool started;
    void Start(){
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.Child("path").ValueChanged += OnStartedRead;
    }
    private void OnStartedRead(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
        if (!args.Snapshot.Exists || args.DatabaseError != null) return;
        started = (bool) args.Snapshot.Value;
        last_action_time = Time.time;
        Debug.Log("game started " + started);
    }
    void Update(){
        float start_period = 5.0f;
        float start_delay = 5.0f;
        if(started == false  && time - last_action_time > start_period) {
            Debug.Log(started.ToString());
            // some code to make started true on the server
        }
    }
    void OnDestroy(){
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.Child("path").ValueChanged -= OnStartedRead;
    }
}
```

When I enter the scene for the first time, I get "game started True" and "True" in the Debug console when the value on server is true. But when I exit the scene and enter it again, I get "game started True" and "False" in the Debug console. And it keeps repeating printing false every 5 seconds even though when the boolean is turned true on the server. Why isn't the member variable updating even though when the ValueChanged event gets triggered?

Comment: `if(started == false...` This means it'll never print if its True so that's why you never get log for True

Comment: Sorry for not being able to explain the problem properly. When the value changed event gets triggered with true value, the started variable is set to be true. But even after the event gets triggered with true value, I keep getting the "False" message in the debug console every 5 seconds. That means the local variable isn't getting updated. That is the problem.